# Apps List RecyclerView not updating when SoftKeyboard is open

Tags: java, android

The app allows users to search their installed apps. The way I have it now, it will let the user search and returns the correct responses when the softkeyboard is closed. I want it to update in real time when the softkeyboard is open. Using the physical keyboard in Emulator updates the RecyclerView no problem. Why does the softkeyboard not do the same?

This is the Fragment class

```
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.justtype_view);
    layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 4);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    jt = view.findViewById(R.id.jtInput);
    jt.requestFocus();
    jt.isFocusableInTouchMode();
    jt.setFocusable(true);
    if (jt.requestFocus()) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) view.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.showSoftInput(jt, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
    }

    Window w = requireActivity().getWindow();
    w.setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(requireActivity(), R.color.status));
    recyclerView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    jtAdapter = new JTAdapter(requireContext(), jt.getText().toString());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(jtAdapter);


    new Thread(this::contactsSearch).start();

    jt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (jt.getText().toString().length()>0) {
                jtAdapter = new JTAdapter(requireContext(), s.toString());
                recyclerView.setAdapter(jtAdapter);
                jtAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                textChange(view);
            } else {
                recyclerView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

This is the Adapter Class

```
public class JTAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<JTAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    public static List<AppInfo> jtList;

    public JTAdapter(Context c, String q) {
        new Thread(() -> {
            PackageManager pm = c.getPackageManager();
            jtList = new ArrayList<>();
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
            List<ResolveInfo> allApps = pm.queryIntentActivities(i, 0);
            if(q.length() == 0) {
                for (ResolveInfo ri : allApps) {
                    AppInfo app = new AppInfo();
                    app.label = ri.loadLabel(pm);
                    app.packageName = ri.activityInfo.packageName;
                    app.icon = ri.activityInfo.loadIcon(pm);
                    jtList.add(app);
                }
                jtList.sort(Comparator.comparing(o -> o.label.toString()));
            } else {
                for (ResolveInfo ri : allApps) {
                    AppInfo app = new AppInfo();
                    app.label = ri.loadLabel(pm);
                    app.packageName = ri.activityInfo.packageName;
                    app.icon = ri.activityInfo.loadIcon(pm);
                    if(app.label.toString().toLowerCase().startsWith(q)) {
                        jtList.add(app);
                    }
                }

                jtList.sort(Comparator.comparing(o -> o.label.toString()));

            }

        }).start();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return jtList.size();
    }

    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull JTAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        try {
            String appLabel = jtList.get(i).label.toString();
            Drawable appIcon = jtList.get(i).icon;
            TextView textView = viewHolder.textView;
            textView.setText(appLabel);
            ImageView imageView = viewHolder.img;
            imageView.setImageDrawable(appIcon);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @NonNull
    public JTAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.jt_item_row_layout, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView textView;
        public ImageView img;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {

            super(itemView);
            textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.jt_app_name);
            img = itemView.findViewById(R.id.jt_app_icon);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                int pos = getAdapterPosition();
                Context context = v.getContext();
                Intent launchIntent = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(jtList.get(pos).packageName.toString());
                context.startActivity(launchIntent);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I expect when I type with the softkeyboard that the RecyclerView will update with the new list of apps. This does not happen until after softkeyboard is closed. The RecyclerView appears blank when typing with the softkeyboard.